# Unable to run Selenium with htmlSuite on Linux with no GUI

Tags: linux, selenium, firefox, profile

I've created a very basic test using Selenium IDE and converted it into an HTML suite. I've setup a VM running CentOS 5.5 to perform Selenium tests.

When I try to use this command,

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.14.0.jar -multiwindow -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://www.example.com" "login-test-suite.html" "sel-results.html"
```

I receive the following output with an exception http://pastie.org/2956400

Someone told me that Selenium is not able to find firefox in /usr/lib/firefox and that was correct, so I created a symlink

```
ln -s /usr/lib64/firefox-3.6 /usr/lib/firefox
```

But still getting the same error. I don't know how to create a profile in firefox via cli as I'm using SSH. My initial thought was Selenium should create a profile itself and if it can't, then definitely something is wrong.

I'll proceed to develop Selenium test in Python only when I get the simple htmlSuite test running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think suite file of your scripts folder, needs to be given folder permission to access by selenium. Hope we can give it in unix. Try to give the permission and try to run one more time. Hope this will help you.

Regards,
Neel

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got it working using this article, http://www.labelmedia.co.uk/blog/posts/setting-up-selenium-server-on-a-headless-jenkins-ci-build-machine.html
(Using xvfb)